# How to show bootstrap confirm box in button click function , angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Given below is the code for submit button click in ctrl.js of my angular.js application

```
namespace.btnClick = function {
     $('#btnID').confirmation({
           'onConfirm' : function () {
            return true;
     },'placement':right,'title' : "Alert"
});
$('#btnID').confirmation('show');
```

**btnID** is the id of the submit button. After clicking submit button for first time, it showing  **bootstrap Confirmation box** with Yes and No button. If I click **Yes** button then its calling onConfirm method, after that again its calling this submit button click function for first time. If I click submit button for second time, its calling this submit button click function but it doesn't show confirmation box.

Comment: Is it possible to have a plunker example ?

Comment: no. Is there possible to find out that where I made mistake in above piece f code? please

Comment: It would be easier to fix your issue using a plunker. We can only guess what's wrong, we can't really figure it out. If you can't setup a plunker because of some sensitive code, you should just setup a simple "Hello World" application implementing this exact scenario.

Comment: Hello Lght, okay. I will do in future. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below code and its working fine

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
  Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
});
```

Kindly refer this: http://bootboxjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You probably needs angular-UI bootstrap library and use it as

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

Please find the library [here.](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: Hello Mahesh Thumar, thanks for your reply.sorry I can't implement this. This is modal popup that I already implemented in my application. but for this scenario, I want bootstrap confirmation box that I mentioned above. kindly tell where I made mistake